# How do I add a loop to this script?

Tags: python, game-engine

How do I add a loop to this script?

```
 import bge
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    owner = cont.owner
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

    cube = scene.objects["Cube2"]
    cone = scene.objects["Cone"]
    sphere = scene.objects["Sphere"]

    prop = owner.get("prop")
    if prop == 1:
        target = cube
    if prop == 2:
        target = cone
    if prop == 3:
        target = sphere

    sensor = cont.sensors["near"]
    sensedObjects = sensor.hitObjectList  


    #objectToTrack = sensedObjects[0] #from original code
    objectToTrack = target

    track = cont.actuators[0]
    track.target = objectToTrack
    cont.activate(track)

    if cont.sensors["Ray"].positive:
        prop = "prop"
        owner[prop] = 2
        print("Ray sensor positive", owner[prop])
    if cont.sensors["Ray1"].positive:
        prop = "prop"
        owner[prop] = 3
        print("Ray1 sensor positive", owner[prop])
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop or https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: @Zelta so you want to *type out* the answer without the link? we could take this off the list.